# ¿Por qué las llaves foráneas no se actualizan en mi base de datos SQLite con DBeaver?

Tags: sqlite, dbeaver

En SQLite versión 3.36 tengo dos tablas dependientes con la definición siguiente:

```
CREATE TABLE `lh_psalmody_join` (
  `groupID` INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  `type` INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  UNIQUE (`groupID`,`type`)
 );
```

---

```
CREATE TABLE `lh_psalmody` (
    `groupFK` INTEGER  NOT NULL,
    `readingFK` INTEGER  NOT NULL,
    `order` INTEGER NOT NULL,
    `antiphonFK` INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    `themeFK` INTEGER DEFAULT NULL,
    `epigraphFK` INTEGER DEFAULT NULL,
    `part` INTEGER DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`groupFK`, `readingFK`, `antiphonFK`),
     FOREIGN KEY(`groupFK`) REFERENCES `lh_psalmody_join`(`groupID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,

     FOREIGN KEY(`epigraphFK`) REFERENCES `lh_epigraph`(`epigraphID`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE,
     FOREIGN KEY(`themeFK`) REFERENCES `lh_theme`(`themeID`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE,
     FOREIGN KEY(`readingFK`) REFERENCES `lh_psalm`(`psalmID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
     FOREIGN KEY(`antiphonFK`) REFERENCES `lh_antiphon`(`antiphonID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

Ahora voy a actualizar una fila en `lh_psalmody_join` con la consulta:

```
UPDATE lh_psalmody_join SET
    groupID = 102030206 
WHERE 
    groupID = 102000206;
```

La fila se actualiza en `lh_psalmody_join`, pero el `ON UPDATE CASCADE` que tengo definido en `lh_psalmody` no ocurre. Esta consulta me arroja 0 filas.

```
SELECT * FROM lh_psalmody WHERE groupFK=102030206;
```

En MySQL tengo definidas las mismas dos tablas con datos similares, pero el `ON UPDATE CASCADE` sí ocurre. Después de ejecutar:

```
UPDATE lh_psalmody_join SET
    groupID = 102030206 
WHERE 
    groupID = 102000206;
```

Cuando verifico en la tabla dependiente:

```
SELECT * FROM lh_psalmody WHERE groupFK=102030206;
```

Veo las filas con el nuevo valor (`102030206`):

```
+-----------+-----------+-------+------------+---------+------------+------+
| groupFK   | readingFK | order | antiphonFK | themeFK | epigraphFK | part |
+-----------+-----------+-------+------------+---------+------------+------+
| 102030206 |        53 |     1 |        552 |      33 |         30 | NULL |
| 102030206 |        54 |     2 |        553 |      34 |         31 | NULL |
| 102030206 |        55 |     3 |        554 |      35 |       NULL | NULL |
+-----------+-----------+-------+------------+---------+------------+------+
```

¿Alguien sabe por qué no funciona en SQLite? ¿Es un problema de este SGBD o es un problema de DBeaver? Estuve mirando si las restricciones estaban apagadas por algún lado, pero no vi nada.

La única solución que me queda es hacer un `UPDATE` de cada fila también en `lh_psalmody`, pero la idea de el `ON UPDATE CASCADE` es evitar esto precisamente.

He creado el siguiente fiddle, y no es un problema de DBeaver, es algo que no funciona al parecer en el mismo SQLite:

```
    CREATE TABLE `lh_psalmody_join` (
      `groupID` INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
      `type` INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
      UNIQUE (`groupID`,`type`)
     );
```

```
    CREATE TABLE `lh_psalmody` (
        `groupFK` INTEGER  NOT NULL,
        `readingFK` INTEGER  NOT NULL,
        `order` INTEGER NOT NULL,
        `antiphonFK` INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
        `themeFK` INTEGER DEFAULT NULL,
        `epigraphFK` INTEGER DEFAULT NULL,
        `part` INTEGER DEFAULT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (`groupFK`, `readingFK`, `antiphonFK`),
         FOREIGN KEY(`groupFK`) REFERENCES `lh_psalmody_join`(`groupID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
    
       --  FOREIGN KEY(`epigraphFK`) REFERENCES `lh_epigraph`(`epigraphID`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE,
       --  FOREIGN KEY(`themeFK`) REFERENCES `lh_theme`(`themeID`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE,
       --  FOREIGN KEY(`readingFK`) REFERENCES `lh_psalm`(`psalmID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
       --  FOREIGN KEY(`antiphonFK`) REFERENCES `lh_antiphon`(`antiphonID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
    );
```

```
    INSERT INTO `lh_psalmody_join` VALUES (102000206,0);
```

```
    INSERT INTO `lh_psalmody` VALUES 
      (102000206,53,1,552,33,30,NULL),
      (102000206,54,2,553,34,31,NULL),
      (102000206,55,3,554,35,NULL,NULL);
```

```
    UPDATE lh_psalmody_join SET
        groupID = 102030206 
    WHERE 
        groupID = 102000206;
```

```
    SELECT * FROM lh_psalmody WHERE groupFK=102030206;
```

| groupFK | readingFK | order | antiphonFK | themeFK | epigraphFK | part |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/SnmcTiFT)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Encontré el motivo del problema en la [documentación de SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html#fk_enable), simplemente las llaves foráneas **están desactivadas por defecto**:

> Foreign key constraints are disabled by default (for backwards
> compatibility), so must be enabled separately for each database
> connection. (Note, however, that future releases of SQLite might
> change so that foreign key constraints enabled by default. Careful
> developers will not make any assumptions about whether or not foreign
> keys are enabled by default but will instead enable or disable them as
> necessary.) The application can also use a `PRAGMA foreign_keys`
> statement to determine if foreign keys are currently enabled.

---

> Las restricciones de clave externa están deshabilitadas de forma
> predeterminada (para compatibilidad con versiones anteriores), por lo
> que deben habilitarse por separado para cada conexión de base de
> datos. (Tenga en cuenta, sin embargo, que las versiones futuras de
> SQLite podrían cambiar para que las restricciones de clave externa
> estén habilitadas de forma predeterminada. Los desarrolladores
> cuidadosos no harán ninguna suposición sobre si las claves externas
> están habilitadas o no de manera predeterminada, sino que las
> habilitarán o deshabilitarán según sea necesario). La aplicación
> también puede usar una declaración `PRAGMA foreign_keys` para
> determinar si las claves externas están actualmente habilitadas.

Entonces hay que ejecutar el siguiente comando antes de modificar los datos:

```
PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;
```

Haciendo eso, el `ON UPDATE CASCADE` sí ocurre, como se puede ver en el fiddle:

```
CREATE TABLE `lh_psalmody_join` (
  `groupID` INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  `type` INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  UNIQUE (`groupID`,`type`)
 );
```

```
CREATE TABLE `lh_psalmody` (
    `groupFK` INTEGER  NOT NULL,
    `readingFK` INTEGER  NOT NULL,
    `order` INTEGER NOT NULL,
    `antiphonFK` INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    `themeFK` INTEGER DEFAULT NULL,
    `epigraphFK` INTEGER DEFAULT NULL,
    `part` INTEGER DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`groupFK`, `readingFK`, `antiphonFK`),
     FOREIGN KEY(`groupFK`) REFERENCES `lh_psalmody_join`(`groupID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE

   --  FOREIGN KEY(`epigraphFK`) REFERENCES `lh_epigraph`(`epigraphID`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE,
   --  FOREIGN KEY(`themeFK`) REFERENCES `lh_theme`(`themeID`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE,
   --  FOREIGN KEY(`readingFK`) REFERENCES `lh_psalm`(`psalmID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
   --  FOREIGN KEY(`antiphonFK`) REFERENCES `lh_antiphon`(`antiphonID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

```
INSERT INTO `lh_psalmody_join` VALUES (102000206,0);
```

```
INSERT INTO `lh_psalmody` VALUES 
  (102000206,53,1,552,33,30,NULL),
  (102000206,54,2,553,34,31,NULL),
  (102000206,55,3,554,35,NULL,NULL);
```

```
-- Activamos las llaves foráneas
PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;
```

```
UPDATE lh_psalmody_join SET
    groupID = 102030206 
WHERE 
    groupID = 102000206;
```

```
SELECT * FROM lh_psalmody WHERE groupFK=102030206;
```

| groupFK | readingFK | order | antiphonFK | themeFK | epigraphFK | part |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 102030206 | 53 | 1 | 552 | 33 | 30 | *null* |
| 102030206 | 54 | 2 | 553 | 34 | 31 | *null* |
| 102030206 | 55 | 3 | 554 | 35 | *null* | *null* |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/GxTLqj0r)

Comment: sqlite es una base muy trivial, aunque esto resuelve el problema, yo no dependeria de ello para nada...

Comment: Cierto @gbianchi, ahora buscaré la forma de tener las llaves foráneas encendidas por defecto. El hecho es que sin saberlo he hecho algunos cambios en los datos y ahora mismo no sé si hay inconsistencias porque las advertencias de violación de restricciones tampoco estarían saltando.